# Need help understanding the solution to a probability question.

Tags: probability-distributions

[image]
$(x)$ is for number of complaints in a month.
$P(X=x)$ is the probability

So $0.16$ probability for $0$ complaints a month.
$0.24$ probability for $1$ complaint a month and so on.

The question is: What is the probability that the insurance company will receive 15 complaints in a year?

The solution:
[image]

15/12 is for 15 complaint/12 months,
1.136 is the standard deviation,
1.1 is the expected value,

I dont understand how p(z≤0.457) = 0.67. How do we get that number?

Comment: From a normal distribution table.

Comment: Can I calculate it with Casio, or an online tool?

Comment: Online -- yes, of course you can. Search online for a "normal distribution table" or a "normal distribution calculator", whichever you prefer. As for calculators, such a Casio, I have no idea because I don't use them. Besides, asking about a "Casio" is not specific enough -- they manufacture a huge variety of calculators; and I presume their more advancded models can do this.